# New Named Calculation Expression for Case Statement?

Tags: sql, ssas

Can any one help with the case statement?

The following CASE STATEMENT is the result in my SQL Management.

```
select
Column1 = case when Column1 = 'true' then 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END ,
Column2 = case when Column1 = 'true' then 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END ,
SHARED = case when Column1='true' AND  Column1='true' THEN 'SHARED' ELSE 'NOTSHARED'
END
FROM Table
```

RESULT:

```
Column1         Column2         SHARED
Y       N       NOTSHARED
N       N       NOTSHARED
Y       N       NOTSHARED
N       N       NOTSHARED
N       N       NOTSHARED
Y       N       NOTSHARED
Y       N       NOTSHARED
Y       N       NOTSHARED
N       N       NOTSHARED
Y       N       NOTSHARED
N       N       NOTSHARED
Y       N       NOTSHARED
Y       N       NOTSHARED
N       N       NOTSHARED
```

I have to create a new named calculation using the above statement. How to do it?

When I try this it is displaying the error:

```
Deferred prepare could not be completed.
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the query to subquery and then you can use it on select statement as below

```
select column1, column2, 
       SHARED = case when Column1='true' AND  Column1='true' 
                     THEN 'SHARED' 
                     ELSE 'NOTSHARED'
                END
 from (    select
           Column1 = case when Column1 = 'true' then 'Y'
           ELSE 'N'
           END ,
           Column2 = case when Column1 = 'true' then 'Y'
           ELSE 'N'
           END 
           FROM Table 
      ) Tab
```

Comment: What is the Tab here means? I am getting error Incorrect syntax near the keywords FROM and select. Should I close it with braces (select column1, column2, 
       SHARED = case when Column1='true' AND  Column1='true' 
                     THEN 'SHARED' 
                     ELSE 'NOTSHARED'
                END
 from (    select
           Column1 = case when Column1 = 'true' then 'Y'
           ELSE 'N'
           END ,
           Column2 = case when Column1 = 'true' then 'Y'
           ELSE 'N'
           END 
           FROM Table 
      ) Tab )

Comment: @vinodkumard `Tab` is an alias of your subqery

Comment: @vinodkumard Does the query `select
Column1 = case when Column1 = 'true' then 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END ,
Column2 = case when Column1 = 'true' then 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END 
FROM Table` work ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a **named calculation** in the data source view of an Analysis Services cube, as I assume from your question, then each clause like

```
case when Column1 = 'true' then 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
```

has to be a separate named calculation which you put into the *Expression* field, and you would put the name into the *Column name* field of the dialog.